# Passing environment variables to a UNIX Script from an AutoSys JIL script

Tags: autosys

JIL script allows the passing of envvars to a command as below.
My question is how to specify the envars in a file on the file system rather than in the JIL script?

```
insert_job: unix_job
job_type: CMD
machine: unixprod
command: /home/scripts/pay
envvars: NAME="user 1"
envvars: JOB=PAYROLL
envvars: PWD=/usr/scripts/dailyrun
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a **profile** attribute in your JIL that points to a script file which loads your environment variables.

```
profile: /your/path/here/config.ksh
```

Inside config.ksh:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
export NAME="user 1"
export JOB=PAYROLL
export PWD=/usr/scripts/dailyrun
```